# Finding the Potential of a Force

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, energy, potential, integration

I'm new on this forum and I need help to solve a problem.
I've got this Force applied on a specific point B in a 3x3 system:

$$F=K*|X|^2*X$$    where X is the position vector of the point B in the system, and K a costant >0 (zero).

The coordinates of the poin B are:

$$X = (\lambda_1 u_1+\lambda_3u_3)$$     where $u_1$ and $u_3$ are the versors of the 3x3 System $(u_1,u_2,u_3)$

Well, I have to determinate the Potential of the force F applied on the point B

Now, I know that the gradient of U is equal to F,

so I simply did the indefinite integral of the force F respect $d\lambda_1$ and $d\lambda_3$

$$F=k*[\sqrt(\lambda_1^2+\lambda_2^2)]^2*(\lambda_1u_1+\lambda_3u_3)=$$
$$=k*(\lambda_1^2+\lambda_3^2)\lambda_1u_1+k*(\lambda_1^2+\lambda_3^2)\lambda_3u_3$$

This is the integral:

$$\int(k*(\lambda_1^2+\lambda_3^2)\lambda_1u_1)d\lambda_1+\int(k*(\lambda_1^2+\lambda_3^2)\lambda_3u_3)d\lambda_3=$$
$$=\frac{k}{4}\lambda_1^4+\frac{k\lambda_1^2\lambda_3^2}{2}+\frac{k}{4}\lambda_3^4+\frac{k\lambda_1^2\lambda_3^2}{2}=$$
$$=\frac{k}{4}\lambda_1^4+k\lambda_1^2\lambda_3^2+\frac{k}{4}\lambda_3^4$$

And this is my result... the problem is that the result should be (because I've got the book's solution of the problem):

$$\frac{k}{4}(\lambda_1^2+\lambda_3^2)^2$$

I've tried to do the derivate of my result and the book result and both have got the same derivative. This mean that both results are the primitive of the Force. I know that the indefinitive integral is a "bunch" of primitives because there should be an additive constant to the result.

So my question is, how can I find the right primitive of the force to achieve the right potential of the force in the specific point B?

Thank you

Comment: If B is a specific point then the lambda coefficients are constants. They are not variables in the force or potential energy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For convenient notation, we work in 3D space with coordinates $(x,y,z)$. We have a force field expressed as $\bf{F}=$$k$$|\bf{X}|^2\bf{X}$ where $ \bf{X}$ $=(x,y,z)$ is a vector. This force can be evaluated at any point in space. If we have a conservative force, then we can express it as the gradient of a potential $\bf{F}=-\nabla{U}$.

Negative the gradient of $\bf{U}=$$-\frac{k}{4}$$|\bf{X}|^4$ gives us $\bf{F}$ (easier to spot this than integrating), which gives the answer you are looking for when evaluated at B (up to a sign which is just convention here).

Comment: Thank u very much for the answer. What you mean with "negative the gradient"?  Maybe there is a rule that I don't know... I mean, how can you say that if F is equal to −∇U, then U is −(k/4)|X|^4. There is some kind of reversal operator of the gradient ∇ that is not an integral? I saw other similar exercise and in some of them they use the integral of the force to find U... so, when can I use the integral and when I can't?

Comment: If $r=|X|$ is a vector, then $\frac{\partial r}{x_i} = \frac{x_i}{r}$. Therefore, $\frac{\partial U}{\partial x_i}= -\frac{k}{4} \frac{\partial r^4}{\partial x_i} = -kx_i r^2 =-F$. Integrating $U$ is the same as finding something whose gradient is equal to $U$, this is what I have done here. The important thing is we are doing all our calculus using $(x,y,z)$ as variables, not the constants $\lambda_i$ as you were doing.

Comment: Ok man! Now I understand! The step that I've missed was the fact that the variables aren't constans and I didn't know the first equation that you wrote! Thank u!!!